# Logging entire response on console show the data. But when i try to get the individual property in typescript it gives undefined. Why?

Tags: typescript, angular5

I am getting some response while catching a socket.io event in angular. when i log the whole response on console its showing all properties but when i try to get individual property then it gives undefined. I am attaching a pic for reference.
P.S: I am new in type Script.

```
this._chatService.onNewUserJoined()
  .subscribe((data:any) => {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data['userName']);
    this.snackBar.open(`${data['userName']} Joined chat room!!!`, "ok", {
      duration: 2000,
    });
  });
```

Thank you[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8aVaC.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your response is an **`array`**, you need to access by using an index or with loop, the following should work good.

```
 console.log(data);
 console.log(data[0]['userName']);
```

Comment: Ohhh Man you saved my day thank you so much. Can you also explain what is the difference and why this worked?

Comment: as i explained above data is an array not a object.